# Xamarin.Forms activate/deactivate toolbar items not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Form MainPage:ContentPage with a ToolbarItems Bar on top. The toolbar items are bound to my ViewModel like so:

```
    <ToolbarItem Text="Sync" Command="{Binding ReloadCommand}" >
    </ToolbarItem>
```

The availability of the Item depends on some logic:

```
    private bool canReloadExecute(object arg)
    {

        bool result = (!IsReloading && (App.GetPersistentSetting("DeviceID") != "") && (App.GetPersistentSetting("BuildingID") != ""));
        return result;
    }
```

There is a separate dialog controlling the DeviceID and BuildingID on a different settings page. Once any of those ids is entered it is persistently stored away

```
 App.SetPersistentSetting("DeviceID",value);
```

Problem is, that the menu items don't change their appearance once my code uses popAsync() to return to the Main page. I need to restart my app to see the changes. According to the debugger, canReloadExecute isn't called. **Why this?**

What I tried to work around this issue is to force a refresh in the MainPage's OnAppearing method like this:

```
    public void RefreshToolbarItems()

    {
        TestApp.ViewModels.MainViewModel mvm = (TestApp.ViewModels.MainViewModel)BindingContext;
        mvm.RefreshToolbarItems();
    }
```

... and in the ViewModel:

```
    public void RefreshToolbarItems()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("BuildingScanCommand");
        OnPropertyChanged("ReloadCommand");
    }
```

but this code runs through but changes nothing, while the Debugger shows that the routine is indeed firing the events, they seem to go nowhere.

Any ideas how I can get my menu going?

**Edit 1: "Show command initalization"**

I am not shre what specifically you mean, but here is the whole code dealing with the command:

```
    private ICommand _reloadCommand;
    public ICommand ReloadCommand => _reloadCommand ?? (_reloadCommand = new Command(ExecuteReloadCommand, canReloadExecute));
    private bool _isReloading = false;

    public bool IsReloading
    {
        get => _isReloading;
        set
        {
            _isReloading = value;
            ((Command)_reloadCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ReloadCommand));
        }
    }

   private bool canReloadExecute(object arg)
    {

        bool result = (!IsReloading && (App.GetPersistentSetting("DeviceID") != "") && (App.GetPersistentSetting("BuildingID") != ""));
        return result;
    }

    private async void ExecuteReloadCommand(object obj)

   {
        IsReloading = true;

        // Some code ...

        IsReloading = false;
    }
```

The goal is to disable the command, if either the command handler is already running, or if the configuration of DeviceID and/or BuildingId hasn't been done yet.

The enable/disable does almost work, if I set the DeviceId and BuildingId, and restart the app, the command is properly enabled or disabled. It doesn't work, however, if I set the Ids in a sub-page and return to the main page.

meanwhile I came to the conclusion, that firing onPropertyChange obviously doesn't make the command check its canReloadExecute. So the question is, how do I trigger this?

Comment: Show us the `Command` initialization

Comment: I appended Edit 1. If you need something else, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue myself, this code works nicely for me:

```
    public void RefreshToolbarItems()
    {
        ((Command)BuildingScanCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
        ((Command)ReloadCommand).ChangeCanExecute();
    }
```